# Disable logback logging for class via system property or env vars

Tags: spring-boot, logback, slf4j

I have spring boot app and using Slf4j (logback). I wanna disable logging for specified class via system property as -Dlogger.... or some other way that doesn't involve creating logback.xml or modifying Java code, how can I do this?

Comment: Just pass it as a system variable, use the name as explained by the Spring boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.log-levels) (which you did read ofcourse!).